# Iterate over the public fields of instances of a class

Tags: c#, lambda

Consider the following.

I have a class A like this:

```
public class A
{
    public int x;
}
```

I also have multiple instances of A in a List.

```
List<A> list_of_As = new List<A>();
// Added a bunch of A instance here..
```

Now here comes my wish: I want a foreach loop in which I access direcly the x members of all the A-s in list_of_As. Can I do something like this?

```
foreach ( var my_x = (player => player.Get_Ping()) in players )
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Careful with wording: *attributes* are not *members*!

Comment: Oh yes. Sry I have spent an awful lot of time with Java recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Linq.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

```
foreach(var myX in list_Of_As.Select(a => a.x))
```

Comment: Yea that is what I was looking for. Thanks, and sorry for the noob question.

Comment: No worries, you may like to visit msdn's "101 linq examples" sometime

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to access all `x` `int` fields?

```
foreach (int x in list_of_As.Select(a => a.x))
{
    //...
}
```